# Should I pass my service locator to all my objects when they need them?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, service-locator

I recently decided that a service locator would be an okay design pattern to access important managers for my game like a world manager (can spawn entities and keeps track of them) and a sound manager. However, I am not sure of the most appropriate way to have access to the service locator. I started by passing a pointer to the service locator I instanced in main, but this is becoming tedious, as I have found everything (projectiles, players, everything!) is needing it in it's arguments.

I am asking this here because I don't think that it is specific to games, but if I am wrong, just let me know.

Am I going about this pattern the wrong way? 
Thanks for your time.

EDIT: Would a singleton solve this problem? They have a global point of access, but I don't think that it is the cleanest solution. Any ideas? Or would that be best?

Answer (score 1):

This is a situation where using a global variable (or a Singleton) may be appropriate. You have to weigh the disadvantages of using a global variable / a singleton against the convenience of not having to pass a reference nearly everywhere. If you feel the disadvantages are unlikely to affect your design/code, then using a global variable can make your code much cleaner.

Some disadvantages of using a global variable are:

- Managing the lifetime of your global can be more difficult. If you define multiple global variables in different translation units (cpp files), the order in which they are instantiated is unspecified, so they'd better not rely on each other during instantiation. One solution would be to store global pointers and instantiate the objects somewhere early in your program (e.g. in main), but then you have to make sure you don't create dangling pointers during the destruction phase of your program.
- You may need to synchronize access to your global variable(s) in a multi-threaded context. With global variables it's harder to use per-thread objects (or proxies) to prevent having to synchronize access.

Additional disadvantages of a singleton can be:

- Not being able to create copies of your class, e.g. for saving or undo.

Comment: Thank you for your information. Are there any alternatives to these two options? Thanks :)

Comment: @Mixerman123 Redesign such that you don't need access to the save object everywhere?

Comment: @D Drmmr How might I go about that if I need access to very separate things like audio logging and entity management? If you have a solution, I would love to see!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am in favour of using a *single* context object everywhere instead of using singletons. Have the context object provide you with functions to give you pointers/references or access to all the different services, managers, etc.

Comment: Yes, a service locator. What I am asking though is how do I have access to that object? Should I have it's method static? If so, how?